# Rails : How to log all exceptions thrown in rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Using a custom ErrorLogger I've written, I am trying to find a way to log all errors happening in any of my rake tasks. One alternative would be to simply add the begin-rescue block to every single *.rake file:

```
# lib/tasks/example.rake
require 'error_logger/error_logger'

namespace :example do
  task generic_example: :environment do
    begin
      ...task code here
    rescue Exception => e
      ErrorLogger.log(e)
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```

But doing it for all task files is not very DRY, so I am wondering if there is a smarter way of doing it.

For instance, I log my controller errors putting the logging logic in the application_controller, so it runs no matter which controller is dealing with the request:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
require 'error_logger/error_logger'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from Exception, with: :error_middleware

  def error_middleware(exception)
    ErrorLogger.log(exception)

    raise error
  end
end
```

What's the best way to do something similar in the rake tasks, writing the logging logic just once and having it applied to all rake tasks? Maybe there is some code I could add to the Rakefile to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this task, by monkey-patching rake as shown below

```
module Rake
  class Task
    alias_method :invoke_without_loggable, :invoke

    def invoke(*args)
      begin
        invoke_without_loggable(*args)
      rescue StandardError => e
        ErrorLogger.log(e)
        raise e
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, Al-waleed, that's very interesting!I have never done a monkey-patch, do you know where I should put this code? And is it indifferent whether I monkey-patch the 'invoke' method or the 'execute' method?

Comment: You can put it anywhere as long as it is loaded by the rake tasks (Rakefile).